# Process Slow Motion Video Effect iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation

How would I go about creating a slow motion effect on a portion of a video recorded or obtained from the camera roll in iOS? I am using the `AVFoundation` framework to select a video from the camera roll or record a video. I intend to add the effect from Time1 to Time2 and then let the video continue at a normal speed.

Comment: Have you found any solution for doing slow motion in video?

Comment: the question is answered on this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17296999/how-to-do-slow-motion-video-in-ios/33914602#33914602

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking you create a slow motion effect by recording at a higher frame rate. So if you record at 60FPS but playback at 30FPS, then you have created a half time slow motion effect. This is how it is done with film. With prerecorded fixed frame rate footage you could playback at a fraction of the original frame rate. If this is to be saved back to a container file, then you will need to adjust the presentation time stamps accordingly.